# Calling pop to route for a route that doesn't exists with NavigatorIOS in react native

Tags: react-native

Please check the below screenshot, I want to pop screen to a specific route in the stack.

I am using this method in NavigatorIOS.

```
    this.props.navigator.popToRoute(
        {
            component: Screen2,
            title: null,
            navigationBarHidden: true,
        }
    );
```

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuQps.png)

Comment: Is the route defined in `this.props.navigator.getCurrentRoutes();` ??

Comment: When I trying to check this condition it's saying  - getCurrentRoutes() not found.